# ISO Emacs [C]Perl-mode colorize hash references like hashes

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

I still use Perl, some new code, and maintaining old code. I use emacs and cperl-mode.  I like syntax coloring.

At first (many years ago) I disliked cperl-mode's special coloring of arrays and hashes, but it has grown on me. To the point where I will sometimes prefer to use a hash rather than a hash reference, just to get the special coloring.  That may not sound so bad - but if I admit to occasionally using a global %hash or $hash{key} rather than an object member $hashref->{key}, just to get the coloring, well, it is bad.  I.e. syntax coloring is making me want to follow bad programming practices.

So, my question is: does anyone have emacs/elisp configuration code to get cperl-mode or perl-mode to colorize a hash reference like $hashref->{key} in the same or similar to $hash{key}?

Let me use bold to indicate the places that might be colored:

- cperl-mode does now:  **$hash**{key}
- what I would like:  **$hash->**{key}

I have done extensive customization of coloring (faces) in emacs - e.g. colorizing to distinguish DEBUG code from non-debug code, TEST from non-test, etc. - but I have not managed to get this syntax coloring in cperl-mode working. (FOLLOW-ON: I eventually got font-lock-add-keywords working, as shown in my answer to my own question below.)

In the example below, you can see that $hashref->{key} is not colored, while $hash{key} is.

[image: example of cperl-mode syntax coloring]

Similarly for array refs, and perhaps other refs.

I realize that coloring refs will only apply to derefs like $hashref->{key}, and not to other stuff like $hashref1 = $hashref2.  I think that I can live with that.

Comment: What I do in cperl mode is to set `cperl-highlight-variables-indiscriminately` to `t` so that `$ref` has the same colour as in `my $ref` (i.e. scalars are coloured when used). Using the same colour for `$var[0]` and `$var->[0]` might obscure the fact they are two different variables.

Comment: @choroba I agree about the risk in coloring $h{k} and $h->{k} the same.  This being emacs, I would assume that we would have hash face and hashref face allowing distinction.

Comment: But you can't tell whether `$hash_ref = function()` is a hash ref or not, so it again will be confusing when used close to `exists $hash_ref->{a}`.

Comment: Your image needs more free-hand circles!

Comment: @choroba agreed - not coloring non-derefs is a loss.  But I think I can live with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dislike answering my own question, but the wild goose chase answer suggested annoyed me enough to figure out what my attempts were doing wrong.

(I hate it when I ask for X, somebody answers Y, and disses X.  Especially when X is doable, as here.)

Here is working code from my .emacs:

```
(defun ag-extend-cperl-font-lock-keywords ()
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
    'cperl-mode
    '(
       (
         "\\($[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*->\\){"
         1 'cperl-hash-face t
         )
       (
         "\\($[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*->\\)\\["
         1 'cperl-array-face t
         )
       (
         "\\($[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*->\\)("
         1 'font-lock-function-name-face t
         )
       )
    t
    )
  )

(ag-extend-cperl-font-lock-keywords)
```

giving

[image]

Just for grins, @choroba's example of multiple types:

[image]

I haven't decided if I should create separate faces for hashrefs, arrayrefs, and coderefs. For now, just using the same face as their non-ref counterparts. Including -> as part of the text colored provides some distinction between non-ref and ref.

Nor have I yet decided if I want to extend to the various other Perl syntaxes.
From https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html:

[image]

But now that I have the font-lock-add-keywords invocation, those details I can fix at my leisure.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `cperl-highlight-variables-indiscriminately` to `t` (via customizing it) to get scalar variables coloured not only when declared but always.
[image]

Using the same colour for `@ref` and `$ref` is confusing, as they are different variable types (and different variables); similarly, it's confusing to use the scalar colour for `$ref` but array colour for `$ref->[0]` as they are the same variable.

Also, Perl being Perl, would you use all three colours here?

```
if (ref $ref eq 'ARRAY') {
    return $ref->[0]
} elsif (ref $ref eq 'HASH') {
    return $ref->{key}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to emphasize is the similarity between $hash{key} and $href->{key} - both being used to access hashes, one directly, the other indirectly.  NOT the similarly between (scalar) variables that contain numbers, strings, hashrefs or arrayrefs.  // yes, I would use all three colors in your second example - in fact the fruit salad effect would probably highlight the fact that something tricky is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want without extending `cperl-mode`. `cperl-mode` doesn't understand references. There's no reference "face" for you to customize, and no "thing" to apply that face to. If you want to render a hash reference like a hash (a la your example) I'd start with modifying [the second regex](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/fb9c52bb7d29c85f3baee770355260830dacea50/lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el#L5838) in the definition of `t-font-lock-keywords-1` in `cperl-mode.el`. That should take care of hash and array refs. Beware of `cperl-highlight-variables-indiscriminately` overriding your changes. If you want to do something fancier, like have a "reference face", you'll have to

1. define a face
2. add the face to customize (if you want)
3. hack `t-font-lock-keywords-1` and apply the face to a regex match

Of course it might just be easier to send a feature request upstream. `cperl-mode` is ancient and could definitely use some modernization.

Comment: In fact I did it without hacking `cperl-mode` itself.

Comment: sorry for downvoting your answer at first.  I was a bit grumpy when you started with a statement that I had just shown to be wrong.  But thanks for looking, and fortunately stackoverflow allowed me to change my -1 to a 0.

Comment: not a problem. "without hacking cperl-mode itself" really should be something like "without hacking some elisp yourself".